# jQuery .click alert

Tags: jquery

Tried searching online for the answer to this question but I'm not really even sure where to begin so I'm hoping someone here can help me out. Basically, I have a page that is just a collection of links inside div tags. What I want to do is call a .click alert for the divs where, when clicked, the alert will display the date of the LAST time that particular link was clicked on, as opposed to just .getDate for today's date. Would I need to set a new variable that takes the date each time the link is clicked and then display that variable in the alert? I don't know if this is something that can even be done, because I'm still relatively new to jQuery, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: last clicked by whoever clicks?

Comment: Well, it's kind of a moot point because only one person will be using this particular page, but in general, yes, the last time anyone clicked would work.

Comment: then you need a database to save last click. This "database" can be represented by a txt but whatever you want to obtain, if it links different users or same user in different times, you'll need server side scripting.

Comment: Or cookies, I'm fairly sure you could do this with cookies too.

Comment: so something along the lines of var date ="//database info//", then $('div').mouseenter(function(){alert(date)}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really, really, really not a bad habit using this way to store this sort of information but if you want to do this you should create this two functions:

```
function SetCookie(cookieName,cookieValue,nDays) {
 var today = new Date();
 var expire = new Date();
 if (nDays==null || nDays==0) nDays=1;
 expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 1000000000000);
 document.cookie = cookieName+"="+escape(cookieValue)
                 + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}
```

and

```
function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
 var theCookie=" "+document.cookie;
 var ind=theCookie.indexOf(" "+cookieName+"=");
 if (ind==-1) ind=theCookie.indexOf(";"+cookieName+"=");
 if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return "";
 var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(";",ind+1);
 if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
 return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+2,ind1));
}
```

using the first one on click event to store cookie with time it has clicked.

```
$("#linkId").click(function(){
 currentTime = new Date();
 var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
 var day = currentTime.getDate();
 var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
 var hours = currentTime.getHours();
 var mins = currentTime.getMinutes();
 var secs = currentTime.getSeconds();
 SetCookie("lastClick",hours + ":"+mins+":"+secs+" - "+day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
});
```

and the second to show up last click:

```
$("#divId").click(function(){
 alert(ReadCookie("lastClick"));
});
```

As i said, this is a little unstable, because it depends on client's cookie and it will work only for one person per time. I'm saying that if A clicks on time X and B click on time Y when A clicks again (after time X and Y) he will get time X, because is the only one time he can read.

[SOURCE](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/settinga.htm)

I tried to make the cookie the more durable as possible.